# Caching issue in Node-RED

Tags: caching, node-red

I'm working on a node-red project which is hosted on AWS S3. There's been an issue where sometimes node-red shows old flows and won't show new flows even if I try to hard reload the browser, and I normally wait for about 1 day for things to get back to normal.

It happens quite randomly and I have no idea if this is because of node-red or aws.

Comment: What happens if you try and access the editor from a different browser? Also are you using a storage plugin? We need a lot more information about the setup on S3

Comment: Even accessing it from a different browser or private window (incognito in Chrome) will not help, so I think it's not browser cache. What kind of info do you need about the setup?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64018688/edit) the question to explain everything about how you have set up Node-RED.